# How can I determine the value of the selected dropdown option using getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, select, html-select, getelementsbyclassname

How can I determine the value of the selected dropdown options using javascript. I can't use id selector so I was trying with document.getElementsByClassName. I understand that returns a set of values.
Here is a simplified code I am trying to use:

```
<div id="MDL" class="dates">
<p>Select Dates and Price</p>
<select class="datevalue">
    <option value="30">17th July - &pound;30</option>
    <option value="45">17th July - &pound;45</option>
    <option value="70">17th July - &pound;70</option>
    <option value="30">18th July - &pound;30</option>
    <option value="45">18th July - &pound;45</option>
    <option value="70">18th July - &pound;70</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="book" VALUE="Buy Now" onClick="book()">

function book() {
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('datevalue');
alert(e.options[.selectedIndex].value);

}
```

But it doesn't work. I've red all the related questions so please do not send me a link to an other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`. Even if you have just one element, it's `e[0]`, not `e`.

Comment: Thanks! Amended the code this works just fine:                                                    var e = document.getElementsByClassName('datevalue');
 alert(e[0].options[e[0].selectedIndex].value);

Answer (score 1):

To get the first element in the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName), use `[0]`. And then get its [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-select-value).

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('datevalue')[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

if what you mean by value is the text inside `option` then use the following code instead :

```
alert(e.options[e.selectedIndex].text);
```

I.E. change `value` to `text`.